# Can we implement a Java library by using Spring Boot?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

As guided by the thread's name, I would like to create a JAVA library by using Spring Boot. I have found this thread: [Creating a library jar using Spring boot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35589437/creating-a-library-jar-using-spring-boot). However, that thread's objectives seem to be solved by implementing it as a REST API.

Currently, I am developing a Spring-based JAVA library by using Spring Boot. And, I have tried to package as a jar file and let another JAVA application to use it in term of a JAVA library. Unfortunately, I found that when the caller application invokes some methods of the added library, **configurations which are defined inside the library do not work at all**.
It also shows an error like "**CommandLineRunner does not exist**".

For more information, a snippet of the pom.xml file is shown below. According to the configuration, I do not include dependencies for web applications.

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.3.3.RELEASE</version>
</parent>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.assertj</groupId>
        <artifactId>assertj-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.0</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

When designed in the correct way this should not be a problem at all. But in detail it depends which features you're using. Since Spring supports external library like JPA, Websocket,..

There are two important annotations to develop a library and use it in another project.

The first one is simply `@Configuration` and the other one is `@Import`.

**Library Project**

Put a class in the root package which looks something like this.

```
@Configuration // allows to import this class
@ComponentScan // Scan for beans and other configuration classes
public class SomeLibrary {
    // no main needed here
}
```

**Other Project using the library**

As usually put a class in the root package of your project.

```
@SpringBootApplication
@Import(SomeLibrary.class) // import the library
public class OtherApplication {
    // just put your standard main in this class
}
```

It is important to keep in mind, that other things might be necessary depending on what your using in terms of other frameworks. 
For example if your using *spring-data* the `@EntityScan` annotation extends the hibernate scan.

Comment: Thank you very much for your clear explanation. So, according to your suggestion, the **other project** is also required to be a **Spring-based application**? Also, if possible, can you correct your example because those two classes have the same name?

Comment: Corrected sorry was a copy paste failure.
If you wana do it that way it is necessary that also the "other" application is a spring app. It is possible to create some sort of self containt library, but this is more complicated and hard to explain in a Stackoverflow post. (I would avoid this approach)

Comment: Thank you. Perhaps, I might ask you the solution via other channels like email later. 

Assume that I will go with making both the library project and the other project as Spring Boot applications. Then, how can I add the library jar into the **other project**?

Comment: Create a maven artifact and reference it as dependency is most likely the best choice. If you just wana develop it local use "mvn install" to install the library in your local maven repo and than add it as dependency to the "other" project. If there's a quest feel free to ask. I think there's a email in my profile.
If this question is done please except the answer, to mark the question as done.

Comment: Sorry, if possible, can you guide me step-by-step on how to **create a maven artifact and reference as dependency**. If not, just point me to some urls for my self-studying. By the way, I am totally fine with your explanation. :-)

Comment: At least your using maven for your project. If you do not know much about maven. It would be the best choice to search for maven tutorials. "spring-boot-starter" in your maven file is an artifact which most likely was loaded from maven central by your IDE(eclispe|intellij) and downloaded in USER_HOME/.m2/some sub folder. Via mvn install you can load your own project into this structure and reference it in the same way as "spring-boot-starter". Companies do usually have their own maven central thing.

Comment: Thank you very much. I know a bit about maven. According to my experience, I have never tried to config a project to be used by another project. Therefore, I do not know how to create such dependencies.