# How to use Spring-Data in you library and how to use this library in you project?

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, maven, spring-data

As you may or may not already see in the title, I try to figure out how to use spring data in my library and how to use this library in my other projects. (all not web-based applications just to clarify)

I am trying to answer for several days for this problem, maybe I am just looking wrong, I am a total beginner as far as spring is concerned.

It only shows errors on startup.

**Find the project here**
https://gitlab.com/roboflax/Spring-Data-In-Library

**Error/s**

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot instantiate interface org.springframework.boot.SpringApplicationRunListener : org.springframework.boot.context.event.EventPublishingRunListener
>       at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.createSpringFactoriesInstances(SpringApplication.java:413)
>       at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.getSpringFactoriesInstances(SpringApplication.java:392)
>       at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.getRunListeners(SpringApplication.java:378)
>       at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:291)
>       at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1118)
>       at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1107)
>       at ThePluginUsingTheLibrary.main(ThePluginUsingTheLibrary.java:24)
>   Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.boot.context.event.EventPublishingRunListener]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.aop.framework.AopProxyUtils.getSingletonTarget(Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;
>       at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:163)
>       at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.createSpringFactoriesInstances(SpringApplication.java:409)
>       ... 6 more
>   Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.aop.framework.AopProxyUtils.getSingletonTarget(Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;
>       at org.springframework.context.event.AbstractApplicationEventMulticaster.addApplicationListener(AbstractApplicationEventMulticaster.java:108)
>       at org.springframework.boot.context.event.EventPublishingRunListener.(EventPublishingRunListener.java:56)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
>       at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:147)
>       ... 7 more

(This could be an approach for an entry point to library but I think there is so mutch more wrong :/ https://stackoverflow.com/a/35790770/9080835)

Please ask if I left more information open and thanks for trying to help me!

**SOLVED**
 I'm now just using the spring io platform for auto devendency management.
Little tutorial for that: [How to use Spring IO Platform and Spring Boot together](http://blog.disid.com/how-to-use-spring-io-platform-and-spring-boot-together/)  and [Spring Data JPA Tutorial: Getting the Required Dependencies](https://www.petrikainulainen.net/programming/spring-framework/spring-data-jpa-tutorial-getting-the-required-dependencies/)

Comment: have you tried the [Spring Data](http://projects.spring.io/spring-data/) tutorials? They mostly are very good in explaining how stuff works with lots of examples....

Comment: did you want  run this library ?

Answer (score 2):

This kind of exception is a sure sign that you have incompatible versions of you dependencies:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.aop.framework.AopProxyUtils.getSingletonTarget(Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object; at
```

Use `mvn dependency:tree -Dverbose` to see the versions of dependencies of your projects. Including conflicts (see https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/examples/resolving-conflicts-using-the-dependency-tree.html for an example).

Only use non-conflicting versions.